# How can I delete a Blob in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob

I am using

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            // process the response from the backend
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.search_text !== "") {
                    $('#search_result_text').html("Your search " + "<font color='red'>" + response.search_text +
                        "</font>" + " in category " + "<font color='red'>" + response.category + "</font>" +
                        " has " + "<font color='red'>" + response.amount_hits_search_text + "</font>" + " hits in:")
                    $('#hits_document').html("all documents: " + "<font color='red'>" +
                        response.amount_hits_document_total + "</font>" + "<br>" + "mgmt. documents: " +
                        "<font color='red'>" + response.amount_hits_documents_mgmt + "</font>")

                    export_csv.style.visibility = "visible";
                }

                // function to export all hit results
                $('#export_csv').click(function() {
                    console.log("trying to download")

                    var blob = new Blob([response.csv], {
                        type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
                    });

                    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, response.search_text + " " + response.category + ".csv")

                    } else {
                        var link = document.createElement("a");
                        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            link.setAttribute("href", url);
                            link.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
                            link.setAttribute("download", "fileName.csv");
                            link.style = "visibility:hidden";
                            document.body.appendChild(link);
                            link.click();
                            document.body.removeChild(link);
                            link.removeChild()
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
                        }
                    }
                })

            )}
)}
```

to create a blob for Internet Explorer.

The button "export_csv" generates a CSV which I am able to download afterwards. But I realized, that the blob is not "overwritten". When I have created 3 CSV files and downloaded them with each click, the fourth CSV and click will lead to download all former 3 CSV/blob files also!

How can I delete each blob after the download?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show more relevant code please? [How is `blobby` formed?](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed)

Comment: @ChrisG The blob file is a csv from an Ajax response

Comment: So you're positive that the Ajax responses are fine? How are you creating there CSV files? Please show more code, there's no way we can help you with this little information.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, The response is absolutely fine. The downloaded CSV fines are fine (utf-8 etc.) With each Ajax response I get another CSV file which I download as blob. For non Internet Explorer part there is the URL.revokeObjectURL(url) method. I am looking for something similar for Internet explorer to delete the blob after the download.

Comment: The problem is that you keep calling `$('#export_csv').click(...)`, adding a new event listener and therefore a new download to the button each time the ajax request finishes. So after you've searched a second time, clicking the button will trigger two downloads. Then three. etc. This is not about deleting blobs, it's about assigning the click handler exactly once when the page loads and merely updating what is downloaded.

Comment: @ChrisG You were absolutely right. I quickly fixed it by simply adding $("#export_csv").off("click"); before each Ajax request! Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big props to @ChrisG.

I could simply fix it by adding $("#export_csv").off("click"); before the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.